# how to make a project as startup project in VS Code and to which layer should I apply migration in .NET

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, entity-framework-migrations

Currently I'm using .NET 6 with VS Code.

My project layers are:

**1)** A webapi layer

It includes

- Controllers
- Connection String
- Program.cs
- `.csproj` file

**2)** A data layer

It includes

- Models
- enums
- `DbContext` class
- Data layer Interfaces and Repositories
- `.csproj` file

**3)** A service layer

It includes

- Service layer Interfaces and Repositories
- `.csproj` file

References and dependencies are added. There are no build errors.

I want to do migrations. To do it, to which layer the migration have to apply?

```
dotnet ef migrations add "Initial Migration"
```

I have done migration when all files were in a in a single project using the above line of code.

My UI layer (webapi layer) is the startup project, right? Should I do anything else than running webapi `.csproj` file?

```
dotnet run --project ./webapi.csproj
```

Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrations are done at Data layer(the layer DbContext class exist).
Webapi layer is the Startup project

To do Migration at specified project:

`dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --project ../Datalayer --startup-project ../WebApiLayer`

To do Updation at specified project:

`dotnet ef database update --project ../DataLayer --startup-project ../WebApiLayer`

Comment: are there no handy ways for doing that? Its annoying to type it so many times....